# How can I use $SERVER in an URL echo string and how do I make $SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] to only be used if needed?

Tags: php, string

I am struggling on this line of code:

`echo "<a href='"$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] .     $sign . img=$img . &shift=1'> -> </a>";`

How Do I handle the quotes right?

My second question:
How can I make the `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` as an individual decision? Can I put an if else into the string? I mean I only want to add the query string if there is one.
Or is there a whole different approach to reach the binding in of the address?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ternary if in line

```
echo "<a href='http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . (trim($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) == ""?$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]."&":"?") . "img=" . $img . "&shift=1'></a>";
```

Comment: Cool, looks very good. I get a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&'` though. :(

Comment: @baustellenServer Fixed the parse error

Comment: It also works theoretically without parse error, but the outcome is `http://localhost/instagram/index.php&img=0&shift=1`. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$base_url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$base_url .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Above is a way to get base_url.

Then you can write:

```
echo '<a href="' . $base_url . '/'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])?$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'&' : '?') . 'img="' . $img . '&shift=1"></a>';
```

Comment: Thanks, looks awesome. I get an `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'` though. :(

Comment: @baustellenServer Should work now?

Comment: It works theoretically without parse error, but the result is `http://localhost/instagram///instagram/index.php&img=`

Comment: @baustellenServer Tell me desired uri so I'll fix it. It seems we have almost there

Comment: @baustellenServer it seems your are working on a subfolder, right?

Comment: I am working on a script for a "gallery". I pull the images from Instagram and want to have a <- and a -> for switching to the next pic. Which brings me to the next trouble: before I can switch I have to pull the `$img`and `$shift`out of the URI before I can add them again. Arrgh. Or is there another way to make a button work for the desired effect on PHP? The URI has to be `/index.php?img=0&shift=0 (or 1)`. Thanks again!!

Comment: `@YahyaE`In this testing this is the URI. In real situation it will be `/index.php?area=mastering&img=0&shift=0`.